# Can't connect to SQL Server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a DB and I followed the [connection string suggestions](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). However, I'm not a DB-guy so some things are, hrmp... less than obvious.

For instance, the DB server is within the network and the connection to it goes from another server, also in the same network. I've used the server name and port to connect to it using Management Studio so it's up and running.

This is my connection string.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
  "integrated security=SSPI;"+
  "server=server.name.as.in.management.studio,4340" +
  "persist security info=False;database=NameOfTheDb";
```

The authentication is done using AD and the error message is 40 - can't find the server. Besides the obvious - the server can't be found - what can I do to trouble-shoot this, obtain more information etc.?

I'm at a customer and their system is not as well documented as one'd like. I get very little information and the coverage is questionable. The person who set up the attrocity is gone since a long time.

Suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**

Following the corrections provided, I'm getting error code 0 - *The requested name is valid but no data of the requested type was found*.

What do I do with this?!   :)

Comment: Missing a semicolon after the server? And I believe "database" should be "initial catalog" (but don't quote me on this). You also might want to look into using a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead.

Comment: It could be a firewall issue.

Comment: you need to put your connection string in brackets, I.E `conn.ConnectionString=("integrated security=SSPI;"+  "server=server.name.as.in.management.studio,4340" +
  "persist security info=False;database=NameOfTheDb");`

Comment: @ReeceCottam Seriously?! I'm not questioning the suggestion. I'm just surprised. Aren't the brackets superfluous there? It isn't a C# feature, is it?

Comment: since .ConnectionString is a method I'd assume it takes the string as a parameter =]

Comment: It's not a method. It's a property. But now I get your point.   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
"integrated security=SSPI;"+
"Data Source=myServerAddress;" +
"persist security info=False;" +
"Initial Catalog=NameOfTheDb";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped **sort of**. Please view my edit in the question. I think we're on a good way, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Sure servce in Managmnet Sql Server is **Start**.
You can do that by go to ---> Control Panel-->All Control Panel Items-->Administrative Tools--Services --> SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) and click **Start**.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString =
    "Data Source=ServerName;" +
    "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
    "User id=UserName;" +
    "Password=Secret;";
    conn.Open();
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, here. The server is up and running. I can access it using the Management Studio. I just can't access the thing from my C# code...

Comment: Please go to toolbar in virtual studio --- to the View --> Server Explorer --->  Add Connection --> Write Server Name then test connection from window add connection and tell me what is happened.

Comment: Ah, you mean the connection from Visual Studio? Done and working perfectly. Both Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio can access the DB. The problem is that my code is executed as a plugin from a CRM and the error message implies (at least to me) that I set up the connection string incorrectly.

Comment: please go to  virtual studio and after the add connection to Server Explorer,when was added. click by mouse on database which is connected and go to propriety , he will see "connection string" copy and pest in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work. The problem is that the code is executed in the context of another user in my plugin. I'm guessing there's a firewall between the plugin and the DB but who knows for sure...   :(